# Why are non-required fields still showing up in my node_edit template using Page Manager

Tags: 7

I am stumped. Certain fields are NOT required and yet they still show up if I add the *base form* to a `node_edit` variant in Page Manager (**Node add/edit form**).

Answer (score 0):

### And I finally found out why:

If the user who's accessing this `node_edit` form variant has the right to update this field even if it's not required and you didn't add it to the form, it will show up as part of the base form in **Node add/edit form** *(Home » Administration » Structure » Pages)*

Hope that helps someone else too.